# Django Paginate by Year

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-class-based-views

I was able to preview the 100 most recent items in my news clipping database on my website's index page with a generic view:

[DPRM](http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com)

Now I need to paginate my database in a separate logical section of my website.  I need to paginate by year.  I don't care how many entries are in each year, I just want to take the year from the URL, fetch the database items from that year (i.e. /newsitems/validyearhere), and present it to the user with a way to navigate through years.  There is a way to do this in Rails but I couldn't find a way in Django.

Will I be able to use the currently deployed model?

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subhead = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publication = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline
```

Will I have to add a redundant Year database field, in addition to the current date field?  Will the schema need to evolve in any way to accommodate this?

I also need it to fail gracefully if the user puts in a year with no entries or data that is not a year.

Please explain this as simply as you can as I am very new to Django and am finding the learning curve steep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the new [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) the easies would be to use the [YearArchiveView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#yeararchiveview)

```
class ArticleYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 100
    context_object_name = 'article_list'
    date_field = 'date'
    allow_empty = True
```

Allow empty is to show the page even when there's no elements for that year

in your `urls.py` you would need something like

```
url(r'^newsitems/(?P<year>\d+)/$', ArticleYearArchiveView.as_view()),
```

Comment: Thx armonge!  This code (with some fixes) works!  http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/newsarchive2003 http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/newsarchive2009 http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/newsarchive2010 but why did the CSS stop working?

Comment: @pyrodney thats for another question but you seem to be using relative paths in your CSS tags instead of absolute ones

Answer (score 1):

Yes your model is fine.. Why not write a class based view?

```
class SomeListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 100
    template_name = "app/template.html"
    context_object_name = "articles" # or use object_list

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.order_by('-date')
```

You can add a different filter in get_queryset to create a list with results by year, and in your template you can iterate over them and create custom buttons (with year info)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering so quickly.  So I would use the URLconf to pass the year value to this view function, and use that in get_queryset, and also drop the paginate_by variable?  How do I filter by year without a field dedicated to only holding year data?